# Fix exit code -2147024891 JetBrains ResharperTestRunner could not start

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2019

I already have Visual Studio 2017 on my development machine. Now to upgrade to Visual Studio 2019. So a fresh install of Visual Studio 2019 16.0.3 with an upgraded Resharper 219.1.1 for both VS2017 & 2019.

Open a test in VS2017 right click and Run All and R# runs the test and all is well. Open same test in VS2019 and Run All and I get:

- MyTests is inconclusive
- And when I hover over the test I see:

[image]

Anyone seen this or can suggest a fix?

Comment: -2147024891 could be ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED/COR_E_UNAUTHORIZEDACCESS. try run VS as admin

Comment: @magicandre1981 that solved it even though I swear I changed the shortcut to run as admin it clearly did not stick. If you want to add that as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `-2147024891` could mean `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` `COR_E_UNAUTHORIZEDACCESS`. So you have a permission issue which should be fixed if you run the Visual Studio as admin when you try to run the .tests